# Android: Json parse

Tags: android, json

I have a Json like this:

```
{
   error_message: 'asdasdasdasdasd',
   error_code:'xxxx',
   indexes:{1,2,5,6}
}
```

I've get error_code and error_message like this:

```
errorInfo.setCode(errorObj.getString(ERROR_CODE));  
errorInfo.setMessage(errorObj.getString(ERROR_MESSAGE));
```

Constant:  ERROR_CODE = "error_code" and ERROR_MESSAGE = "error_message".
But I don't know how to get 1,2,5 and 6 from indexes.
Please help me with this!

EDIT: My json:

```
{
   "error_message":"asdasdasdasdasd",
   "error_code":"xxxx",
   "indexes":[1,2,5,6]
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid json

Comment: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Not a valid json.
It should be like this:
{
   "error_message": "asdasdasdasdasd",
   "error_code":"xxxx",
   "indexes":[1,2,5,6]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your json should look like this:

```
{"error_message":"asdasdasdasdasd","error_code":"xxxx","indexes":[1,2,5,6]}
```

And how to parse the `indexes`

```
JSONArray indexes = errorObj.getJSONArray("indexes");
List<Integer> indexesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length(); i++) {
    indexesList.add(indexes.getInt(i));
}
```